# Poisson Process with $\lambda = 3$, suppose $6$ cars arrive after $2$ hours, what is the probability only $1$ arrived in the first hour?

Tags: statistics, poisson-process

> Suppose the number of cars arriving at a gas station per hour follows a Poisson Process with $\lambda = 3$, Suppose $6$ cars arrive after $2$ hours, what is the probability only $1$ arrived in the first hour?

So I know that $P(X_t=k)=e^{\lambda t}\frac{(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$ represents the probability the process is at k at time t.

So because the states are independent, I should just have the $P(X_1=1)P(X_1=5)$? Since the probability of $5$ cars arriving in the 2nd hour should be the same as the probability $5$ arrive in the first hour?

Which gives me $P(X_1=1)P(X_1=5)=(3e^3)(\frac{3^5e^3}{5!})$?

Or does independence mean knowing the total after $2$ hours doesn't matter? And I only need to compute $P(X_1=1)$

Comment: If X = number that arrive in the first hour and Y = number that arrive in 2 hours then you want $P(X=1|Y=6)$ where Y is Poisson with mean rate 6/2 hours.

Comment: @Paul Im not sure how to find that then I'd have $P(X=1, Y=6)/P(X=1)$

Comment: Should be $P(Y=6)$ not $P(X=1)$. Think about Y in terms of $X_1$ = number that arrive in the second hour?

Comment: @Paul I don't know. Is it not true that the probability of k arriving in the 2nd hour is the same as k arriving in the first hour?

Comment: It is. Can you write $P(X=1, Y=6)$ in terms of X and $X_1$?

Comment: @Paul So is it $P(X_1=1)P(X_1=5)/P(X_1=5)$

Comment: Nearly, but the only change is that $P(X=1, Y=6) = P(X=1, X_1=5)$. There must be 5 arrivals in the second hour. NOW you can use independence of intervals. It is very important to always be very clear exactly what your variables are. In this case there are three different variables X, Y and $X_1$

Comment: @Paul what is X?

Comment: See comment 1 above

Comment: @Paul Is $P(X=1)=P(X_1=1)$?

Comment: X is the number of arrivals in the first hour, $X_1$ the number of arrivals in the second hour. Not quite the same thing, but they have the same probability distributions and are independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul gave some good hints — I’ll flesh it out a bit if that helps.

So we know that over 2 hours we got 6 cars and want to know if only 1 of those 6 arrived in the first hour.

Let $X,Y \sim \text{Poi(3)}$ and $Z=X+Y  \implies Z\sim \text{Poi(6)}$

Then $P(X=1|Z=6) = \frac{P(X=1,Y=5)}{P(Z=6)}$

The numerator is essentially one of the many ways you can get 6 cars in two hours.

So we have, by independence:

$$P(X=1,Y=5) = \left(e^{-3} \frac{3^1}{1!} \right)  \left(e^{-3} \frac{3^5}{5!} \right)= e^{-6}\frac{3^6}{5!} $$

Denominator is $P(Y=6)= e^{-6}\frac{6^6}{6!}$

So we get

$$P(X=1|Z=6) = 2^{-6}$$